# AngularJS Bootstrap Modal - Change template onclick()?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-bootstrap

I've currently got two separate modals.  When a button is clicked, the first modal is loaded.  If a specific button is clicked within this modal, I want to load a different modal.  However, rather than have the brief flash that occurs transitioning between modals, I was wondering if there is simply a way to use the current modal but change the template inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this. I'll explain the latter because it's simpler

- Use ngRoute
- use `ng-show` or `ng-if`

So format the HTML in your modal something like this:

```
<modal>
    <div ng-if="modal == 'one'">
        ... modal one content
    </div>
    <div ng-if="modal == 'two'">
        ... modal two content
    </div>
</modal>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.onClickSecondModalButton = () => {
    $scope.modal = 'two'
}
```

You can toggle between your two modals without the animation flash by changing `$scope.modal` to either `'one'` or `'two'`.